# Is DKIM and SPF sufficient to avoid inbound email spoofing from a certain domain?

Tags: email, spf, dkim

Is DKIM and SPF sufficient to avoid inbound email spoofing from a certain domain? For example, can I trust that an email from joe@gmail.com with valid gmail.com DKIM and SPF is really from joe@gmail.com?

Comment: This is related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689286/how-to-prevent-inbound-email-spoofing I decided to post them as different questions, because the one in the link seeks a solution of a more general problem that this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the bounds of your question, yes.  As long as you have a good signature that matches the record published by the email sender, you can be assured that it's valid (within the bounds of the encryption security, don't trust keys less than 1024 bits).

[DMARC](http://www.dmarc.org/faq.html) is the coordinating standard that informs servers of whether they SHOULD accept email that has a failing signature.  gmail currently published a DMARC record saying to accept all email from gmail.com, even if it has a failing signature.  That makes things a little more complex.